# How to unselect input content when focus on it by pushing tab key?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input, unselect

In an html form,
When you use tab to go on next input it select all the content by default,
How to unselect it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `target.selectionEnd` to 0 on focus event

```html
<input (focus)="unselectOnFocus($event)">
```

```js
unselectOnFocus(event: Event): void {
  event.target.selectionEnd = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set #myInput and bind the focus event
`<input #myInput (focus)="onFocus()">`

```
@ViewChild('myInput') myInput: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
```

and

```
onFocus() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myInput.nativeElement.setSelectionRange(0,0);
    }, 0)
}
```

The timeout is required because when you select an input with the tab key, the text is automatically selected right after the focus event.

Answer (score 0):

For setting the elements as unselectable, you can use `tabindex = -1` attribute in the input element like following-

`<input tabindex='-1'>`

> A negative value (usually tabindex="-1") means that the element is not reachable via sequential keyboard navigation, but could be focused with Javascript or visually by clicking with the mouse.

You can check more about this here- [tabindex MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Hope this will help you.